# How can I pass/create a fake media stream to Edge/IE WebDriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, browserstack

There are some flags to create a fake media stream for web camera recording. For example:

'--use-fake-device-for-media-stream', '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream' (Chrome);

'make.navigator.streams.fake' (Firefox).

Are there any flags for Edge/IE browser to pass them to WebDriver capability (Selenium::WebDriver.new :remote, { url: url, desired_caps: caps })?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no such BrowserStack specific custom capability to pass fake media stream on IE and edge. However, you can use the same on chrome and firefox as you have mentioned above. The Chrome Option 'use-fake-device-for-media-stream' is used to grant camera access. However, you can use the 'use-fake-ui-for-media-stream' Chrome Option that will handle the scenarios for 'use-fake-device-for-media-stream' as well('Use you Microphone' OR 'Use your camera' popup).

Comment: Until now, I have used these flags to simulate cameras in chrome and firefox, but now I need similar flags for IE and Edge, which I can't find